# Homonyms. [ghost] is a tag for Python Webkit client *and* blogging platform

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

There is an old tag [ghost](/questions/tagged/ghost) for Python Webkit client. But [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ghost) start to appear that ask about Ghost blogging platform.

How to deal with homonyms? Create separate tags?

Comment: An apt subject for Halloween :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Python Webkit client has a dedicated tag: [ghost.py](/questions/tagged/ghost.py) Any question about Python Ghost using the [ghost](/questions/tagged/ghost) should be retagged instead; I've gone ahead and done so.

Ditto for the blogging platform: it has [ghost-blog](/questions/tagged/ghost-blog), any questions using [ghost](/questions/tagged/ghost) should be retagged, again I've done so.

The rest of the tag use was very muddled. We had Symantec Ghost (both questions off-topic), Ghost-Installer, Friendly Ghost Language, ghosting (in the context of UIs), and anything unexplainable (ghost database constraints, ghost html tags appearing, etc.)

I've burninated the rest of the tag; [ghost](/questions/tagged/ghost) is now no more:

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Sounds like ghost should be burninated.

Comment: Is there some way to eliminate the tag wiki on it? Otherwise the tag will hang around indefinitely.